# Изменение размера большого jpeg файла

Tags: delphi, jpeg, resize

Нужно изменить размер большого jpeg-файла (экспериментирую с файлом 18000x7000), как это делается без отжирания всей памяти? я шерстил инет и пишут, что библиотеки типа nativejpg и подобные умеют это, но у меня все равно съедается куча памяти и в итоге ошибка типа

> Out of memory

Или

> Not enough storage is available to process this command

Вроде как-то можно построчно или поблочно, но не нашел вразумительных примеров.

Comment: помимо проблем с памятью - есть ещё и другая проблема - http://m.habrahabr.ru/post/252175/ - тут пример её решения. рекомендую сразу обратить на неё внимание.

Answer (score 1):

> Вроде как-то можно построчно или поблочно, но не нашел вразумительных примеров.

Называется это проецирование части файла в память, File Mapping. Хоть терабайты так читайте)

Но придется работать самостоятельно с самим форматом файла.